# How to enable ssh-rsa in sshd of OpenSSH 8.8?

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, openssh, sshd

Since OpenSSH release 8.8 ssh-rsa is disabled in OpenSSH sshd:

```
$ ssh-audit 1.2.3.4
# algorithm recommendations (for OpenSSH 8.8)
...
(rec) +ssh-rsa                              -- key algorithm to append
...
```

Archlinux forum thread "[Latest sshd not accepting key algorithms](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1995438#p1995438)" recommends:

```
$ grep PubkeyA /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
```

Though that configuration snippet doesn't enable ssh-rsa in openssh-8.8p1-1 on 5.10.74-1-raspberrypi4-ARCH, not even after a restart of `sshd`.

How to force OpenSSH sshd release 8.8 to enable ssh-rsa?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To permit using old RSA keys for OpenSSH 8.8+, add the following lines to your `sshd_config`:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com

PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

Other distributions (then Arch on RPi) might support the more secure [xmss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_signature_scheme) keys, which are [recommended for use by latest NIST papers](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-208/final)

```
HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-xmss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-xmss@openssh.com

KexAlgorithms=+sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com

PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-xmss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-xmss@openssh.com
```

Comment: Is there a non 
US (f.e. European, Australian, South American, Canadian) recommendation to use XMSS over 2048 bits RSA?

Comment: You can find the solution here https://serverfault.com/questions/1106758/ssh2-fails-authentication-with-a-working-key-converted-with-puttygen-due-to-dep/1117025#1117025

Comment: With OpenSSH 9.0 I also have to add `RequiredRSASize 1024` to connect an old embedded device as explained in https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6973518

Comment: @akostadinov I would recommend against that. Use something like `ssh -oCiphers=+aes128-cbc  -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha user@host` to connect instead of adding insecure global option

Comment: I didn't say it must be global. I never do global. If necessary for a specific host only.