sshd: Unable to negotiate key algorithm
I have all 3 main key types generated on my server:
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

but when do: sshd -T | grep -i HostKeyAlgorithms, it lists the following output:
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com
rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-ed25519
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com
sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
rsa-sha2-512
rsa-sha2-256

conseguently, I cannot connect with a sftp client to this server, and when I enable debug, I see:
sshd: debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
sshd: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
sshd: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
sshd: debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 [preauth]
sshd: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: (no match) [preauth]
sshd: Unable to negotiate with 178.255.22.33 port 36626: no matching  host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
sshd: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]

my sshd server is: OpenSSH_9.2, OpenSSL 3.0.14 4 Jun 2024

Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss appears to indicate the client isn't able to do any new algorithms.  What is the client?  How has it been configured?

OpenSSH 8.8 up no longer supports ssh-rsa by default; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674582/how-to-enable-ssh-rsa-in-sshd-of-openssh-8-8 . If on RedHat family (you don't say) you often need to set the systemwide cryptopolicy as well as or instead of setting sshd_config directly; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723314/rocky-linux-9-not-accepting-sftp-connections-from-old-dreamweaver-version- . There are also questions about this on other Stacks.

@Stephen Harris - the client is Midnight Commander 4.8.22
